# Excel Power Query get a list of files including the names of empty folders and subfolders

Tags: excel

I need to get a list of all the files and folder names, including empty folders. Is there a way to do this in Excel's power query. Currently it only lists filenames, but not empty folders. I've tried the "cmd" dir print list, but I get an "UNC" error message because it's the folders and files are in a network drive. I actually prefer cmd because it's super fast. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Browse an UNC path using Windows CMD without mapping it to a network drive](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/browse-an-unc-path-using-windows-cmd-without-mapping-it-to-a-network-drive) for some tips. They make use of popd and pushd

Comment: thanks, but too afraid to potentially mess up the network drive with all those thousands of files and folders. i'm checking in to power query ... slow slug ... but i think i'll combine list of folders and the files ... unless there's other options.

Comment: Also check windows PowerShell. It's slower than CMD (on network drives) but might be faster than Power Query

Comment: Our IT person gave me instructions how to map the network drive to a letter; then I did a cmd "dir \b \s > [my-c-drive\list.txt]" and wala! got my list; loaded to excel delimited into columns. (You learn something new everyday). So much easier with cmd....geezus.